# jsonobjects sudently return empty

Tags: php, mysql, json

I was able before to receive json array, now I am receiving empty like this

`{"result":[]}` this is the [url](http://justedhak.com/Files/get_data.php)

this is the php code

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db);

$sql = "select ID,NAME, URL from OBJECTS";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('ID'=>$row[0],
'NAME'=>$row[1],
'URL'=>$row[2]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

this is my database

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NAME` is a reserved keyword in MYSQL, I bet you shall change the column name to something like `objects_name`, then you fetch the query properly. Or you can quote the columns, like :

```
$sql = "select `ID`,`NAME`, `URL` from `OBJECTS`";
```

Comment: you were right , adding single quotes solved my issue.

Comment: Good to hear that dude :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems what `mysqli_fetch_array($res))` returns empty result.
You can check this: add echo into cycle:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    print_r($row);
    array_push($result,
    array(
        'ID'=>$row[0],
        'NAME'=>$row[1],
        'URL'=>$row[2]
    ));
}
```

Check also connect with database. Add these two lines before connect to show errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I am not that good in php can you explain how to add that in the code

Comment: And check connect with database